# IOS Static library how to, and issues

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries

I read about IOS static library creation/issues in many posts, StackOverflow questions, blog and so on... but now i'm really confused :)

Why not to create a unique question to understand this argument and avoid to move across 100 different resources ? 
I try to merge here some major questions about static library:

- How to create static a library (i mean best
  practices ...) ?
- How to build/compile library in a
  universal way (Architecture
  independent) ?
- How to compile library that can use
  categories (the "-ObjC, -all_flags"
  issue) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this guide and the wiki along with it will be very helpful in assisting whatever you are trying to achieve.  [Guide Link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)

Comment: Bro can the link is dead can u help me to get anything related to the question

Answer (score 1):

Check out Karl Stenerud's [iOS-Universal-Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework%20iOS-Universal-Framework)  template on github.com.  It provides a great template for creating a universal framework that wraps around static libraries.  This helps alleviate some of the issues associated with using and distributing static libraries.  I've used it on a couple of projects:  https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/BDHoverViewController

Good luck.

Comment: the iOS-Univeral-Framework link is broken, but this similar one works:
https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework